# HTML Length of a DIV is not equal to the AJAX Loaded HTML Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="SomeDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Content of 'script.js':

```
$(function() {
    function load_text() {
        $.get('test.html').done(function(data) {
            // Check this condition below.
            if ($.trim($("#SomeDiv").html()).length != $.trim(data).length){
                $("#SomeDiv").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(load_text, 2000);
});
```

Here is the Content of 'test.html':

```
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

The above test.html has just that line of code nothing other than that. So Every time when the AJAX will load it will return the same HTML and populate the DIV tag with that over and over. According to the if condition the HTML inside #SomeDiv and the Loaded HTML will not be equal for the First Time After That it should be equal and should not Repopulate the DIV.

But it seems that the lengths are different even after it loaded for the first time. This just hit me! How can it be possible? I am loading same content then I have fetched the same content from another file and compared with previously loaded content but they are not equal...

So is that normal or is there any other way to make it not populate the DIV after first load?

What I am trying to do is if the loaded content is different then show it otherwise don't show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: you *were* (before edit) trimming the `length` due to incorrect bracketing :)

You are comparing raw text string to "structured" HTML (after parsing elements can be added to the DOM and whitespace can change).

Try comparing *like* with *like* (convert it to DOM elements first):

```
// Need to wrap the incoming elements in a parent
var $data = $('<div>').html(data);
if ($.trim($("#SomeDiv").html()).length != $.trim($data.html()).length)
```

Comment: Sorry about that Misplaced Trim, I have corrected it. But The code you have given is not working either. I just Copied and pasted your if statement. Still it shows different and loads every 2 seconds.

Comment: Nop! Just that one line. `<div>Hello World!</div>` No blank spaces either. Though I am trimming it.

Comment: See update... the incoming HTML needs to be wrapped in an element for `.html()` to work. This also allows for multiple top-level elements

Comment: Sorry, your comment example does not match the new code. Please try the update. The wrapper element *is* important. (maybe calling it `$data` was a bad idea as it looks similar to `data`) :)

Comment: Yes! You are a genius... That update works... Thanks! I am marking it right answer!